# go to the zoo vs. go to a zoo vs. go to zoos vs. go to zoo

Tags: idiomatic-language

> go to the zoo

> go to a zoo

> go to the zoos

> go to zoo

As far as I remember, the first one, 'go to the zoo' is what I remember.

Q1: 'go to the zoo' means, in general, any kind of zoo or a specific zoo?

Q2: What are the other expressions like? (go to zoo, go to the zoos, go to zoo)

Comment: You can remove "go to zoo" because it is simply wrong. Also, you can add: "go to zoos". This question has been answered many times here for other situations but one that show the grammar of them.,

Comment: Since zoos are not all that common, _the zoo_ normally means 'the one nearest to where you are'.

Comment: Going to zoos was what we did when we traveled. Going to the zoo, going to the park, going to lake=all near to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The zoo"  The specific zoo is detemined, probably by context.  For example it might be "the big famous zoo in the city" or "the zoo that we usually go to" or "the zoo that we were talking about yesterday"

"A zoo" is an undetermined zoo.

"Zoos" is plural, it means multiple zoos, two or more. "Going to zoo" is not correct English.

So:

> Daddy's taking us to the zoo tomorrow.

Suggests that you know which zoo, and if the speaker is from New York, it is probably Central Park Zoo

> Papa's taking us to a zoo tomorrow.

Suggests you don't know which zoo.

Comment: I'd like to believe you are better at Eng. than Math. What is true?

Comment: I don't think you can compare.  I'm a native speaker of English and a Maths teacher. It is like saying "are you better at playing the piano or tennis"!! impossible to compare.